# Get ID of row inserted by trigger during INSTEAD OF INSERT

Tags: python, view, sqlite

I've just come across views and I think they're a pretty neat idea, however I've hit an issue in that I can't find out the ID of the row that was just inserted in an intercept trigger.

I'm not able to find much info from google so here's an example with the issue. Each time I insert a row, `lastrowid` returns `0`, even though it's being inserted successfully. Is there some way I could return the row ID from the trigger?

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE Test(
    row_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    val1 INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    val2 INTEGER DEFAULT 0
)
""")

cursor.execute('CREATE View TestView AS SELECT val1, val2 FROM Test')

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TRIGGER trig INSTEAD OF INSERT ON TestView
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Test (val1, val2) VALUES (NEW.val1, NEW.val2);
    END;
""")

insert = 'INSERT INTO TestView (val1, val2) VALUES (10, 10)'
print(cursor.execute(insert).lastrowid)
#0

insert = 'INSERT INTO TestView (val1, val2) VALUES (10, 10)'
print(cursor.execute(insert).lastrowid)
#0

insert = 'INSERT INTO TestView (val1, val2) VALUES (10, 10)'
print(cursor.execute(insert).lastrowid)
#0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done any prior inserts getting 0 from that is normal, expected behavior.

From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html)

> If an INSERT occurs within a trigger then this routine will return the rowid of the inserted row as long as the trigger is running. Once the trigger program ends, the value returned by this routine reverts to what it was before the trigger was fired.

Comment: Is there any way I could somehow get that row ID from the trigger? Not a major issue if not though, I just quite like the idea of using views for all my tables that have a `state` column, so that `INSERT` and `DELETE` actually just change the underlying state.

Comment: @Peter doing the insert and then getting the max rowid from the real table, all in one single transaction, will work in most cases.

Comment: That sounds like race conditions could still be an issue, which is one thing I'd definitely like to avoid (I may be building a python wrapper over it all, so if something gets the wrong value, it'd be quite difficult to debug). Eventually I plan to move to mysql once IT eventually get it sorted, so I'll properly revisit views then, in the meantime I'll just avoid using them if I need the ID :)

Comment: @Peter That's why do you both steps in a single transaction; so that it's atomic as far as any other connections are concerned.